# PHP Server over WiFi Not Ethernet

Tags: php, webserver

My PC is connected to two different networks, one via ethernet and one via WiFi.

When I start my PHP server it is only accessible to machines on the ethernet LAN rather than the WiFi. Is it possible to force it to be served over WiFi instead of Ethernet other than just unplugging the Ethernet?

Comment: What php server are you using? This question *might* be off-topic since it's not directly related to programming, but server and network.

Comment: Determine what IP address is bound to the wireless card and specify when starting the dev server. `php -S 192.168.0.1:8000`

Comment: Could move this to [*Server Fault*](https://serverfault.com), I think.

Comment: @castis wow so simple, a little ashamed I didn't try that haha. Thanks!